# Compressing data in Apache Flume

Tags: compression, apache-kafka, flume

I am reading data from Kafka and sinking into HDFS. Is there any way that Flume can compress data and store in HDFS. (Data is not compressed in Kafka)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these two parameters in the sink config:

`hdfs.codeC= one of following -> gzip, bzip2, lzo, lzop, snappy`
`hdfs.fileType=CompressedStream`

More information is available in the [flume user guide](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)